# Placing uint32_t into array of uint8_t

Tags: c++, sockets, uint

So I have the following code:

```
uint32_t length = 1;
uint8_t buffer[5];

buffer[0] = htonl(length);

std::cout << (uint32_t)*buffer << std::endl;
std::cout << htonl(length) << std::endl;
```

The second to last line prints out 0, the last line prints out 16777216.....why....?

Comment: You don't appear to be initialising buffer. Why not?

Comment: Actually, I just realized, you only initialize `buffer[0]`.

Comment: @Ethan Instead of presenting this worst practice code, it might be more productive to tell us about the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: The problem is solved. I just always thought that this work and did not know why it was not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not actually putting the `uint32_t` in the array of `uint8_t`s. Instead, you are placing it in `buffer[0]`. Since length is much larger, only the lowest 8 byte will be stored. And since you've called `htonl(length)`, the lowest 8 bytes are actually all 0 (at least if your host system is using a different byte-order than the network - and this seems to be the case here).

If you actually want to use the first four elements of `buffer` to be used to store `length`, you have to tell the compiler to re-interpret them as a `uint32_t`.

```
uint32_t length = 1;
uint8_t buffer[5];

(uint32_t&)*buffer = htonl(length);

std::cout << (uint32_t)*buffer << std::endl;
std::cout << htonl(length) << std::endl;
```

Not that it's a good idea to do, though ..

Comment: It's always been my understanding that in C you can do things like this. It will simply spill over to the rest of the array....however I am compiling with C++. Is the C++ the difference?

Comment: It would be the same in C. If you wrote `int i = 10000000000UL` the compiler would "cut" the value down to size to store it inside. Assignments like that will never spill over into other memory. With the `(uint32_t&)` I'm telling the compiler to treat the memory area that `buffer` points to like a `uint32_t` and thus it'll be able to store the value without cutting it down.

Answer (score -1):

The second to last line prints out zero coincidentally -- you never stored anything in `buffer`. You set `buffer[0]` to a value that wouldn't fit there and left the rest uninitialized.

The last line prints out 16,777,216 because your platform is little-endian and `htonl` switches to big-endian format, so your 0,0,0,1 becomes 1,0,0,0. That's a one in the 256^3 place, and 1 * 256^3 = 16,777,216.

Comment: The first paragraph isn't true. He stored in `buffer[0]` and in the `cout` he dereferenced `buffer` which gives him the first element of the array. It prints 0 because he called `htol()` which switches around byte order and causes the lower 8 bytes (which are copied into `buffer[0]`) to be 0.